# Spring/Hibernate - Get result from Stored procedure without using @Entity in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

We have a Stored Procedure in MS SQL that returns some result set which doesn't match any DB table. And we want to map the result to plain java POJO without using @Entity annotation. But if we call

```
entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("schema.myProcedure",
                        PlainPojo.class);
```

it will fail for `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity` exception

I know there is *@SqlResultSetMapping* annotation but it needs to be placed on Entity class ? and this doesn't work

```
@Repository
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mapping")
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository
```

only this

```
@Enity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mapping")
public class MyEntity
```

but we don't want entity class for this... so place it on another entity ?? (no really)

- is it possible to place it somewhere else ?
- or is it possible do it in code ?

  another solution ?
- Is it possible to make something like transient Entity ? -> use @Entity annotation without creating DB table etc.

Comment: Do you found a solution? We ran into the same problem and we dont find something that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Spring @Procedure to call StoredProcedure without binding to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524189/using-spring-procedure-to-call-storedprocedure-without-binding-to-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a complex solution on stackoverflow and <strike>reinvent the wheel</strike> maybe this will help for some one, who need to call stored procedures many times in project.

The main idea is write custom annotation similar *@StoredProcedure*, but independent of *@Entity*

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomNamedStoredProcedureQueries {
     /**
     * Array of CustomNamedStoredProcedureQuery annotations.
     */
     CustomNamedStoredProcedureQuery[] value();
}
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomNamedStoredProcedureQuery {
    /*
    * The name of the stored procedure for call.
    */
    String name();
    /*
    * The name of the stored procedure in the database.
    */
    String procedureName();
    /*
    * The scheme name of the database.
    */
    String schemeName();
    /*
    * The name of the package that contains stored procedure in the database.
    */
    String packageName();
    /*
    * Information about all parameters of the stored procedure.
    */
    CustomStoredProcedureParameter[] parameters() default {};
    /*
    * The names of one or more result set mappings, as defined in metadata, when you need custom mapping.
    */
    ProcedureRowMapper[] resultSetRowMappers() default {};
    /*
    * The names of one or more result set mappings, as defined in metadata, when you need 1 to 1 mapping.
    */
    ProcedureResultClass[] resultSetMappers() default {};
}
@Target({})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomStoredProcedureParameter {
    /** Name of strored procedure parameter.*/
    String name() default "";
    /** JDBC type of the parameter.*/
    int type();
    /** Parameter mode.*/
    ParameterMode mode() default ParameterMode.IN;
}
@Target({})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ProcedureResultClass {
    /* Name of procedure parameter*/
    String name();
    /* Class of object using for mapping */
    Class<?> resultClass();
}
@Target({})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ProcedureRowMapper {
    /* Name of cursor field for use mapper*/
    String name();
    /* Class of object using for mapping, must extend BeanPropertyRowMapper */
    Class<? extends BeanPropertyRowMapper> mapper();
}
```

As mentioned before use *ProcedureResultClass* when you need to map resultSet 1 to 1, fields must have the same name.

Use *ProcedureRowMapper* when you need some custom mapping, you can *@Override* **mapRow()** method, and map it manually, or you can *@Override* **initBeanWrapper()** if you just need to convert some fields in specific way.

So, next we need a method that makes it work. Put it in init method of your application, like *@PostConstruct* of main method.

```
ProjectUtils {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ProjectUtils(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(DataSource);
    }

    private static Map<String, SimpleJdbcCall> storedProcedureContainer = new HashMap<>();


    public void initStoredProcedure() {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
        Set<Class<?>> classList = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(CustomNamedStoredProcedureQueries.class);

        for (Class<?> clazz : classList) {
            CustomNamedStoredProcedureQueries queriesAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(CustomNamedStoredProcedureQueries.class);

            for (CustomNamedStoredProcedureQuery queryAnnotation : queriesAnnotation.value()) {
                SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                        .withSchemaName(queryAnnotation.schemeName())
                        .withCatalogName(queryAnnotation.packageName())
                        .withProcedureName(queryAnnotation.procedureName());
                Set<SqlParameter> parameters = this.getDeclaredParameters(queryAnnotation.parameters());
                jdbcCall.declareParameters(parameters.toArray(new SqlParameter[0]));

                Map<String, RowMapper<?>> rowMappers = getDeclaredRowMappers(queryAnnotation.resultSetRowMappers(), queryAnnotation.resultSetMappers());
                 rowMappers.forEach((parameterName, rowMapper) -> jdbcCall.addDeclaredRowMapper(parameterName, rowMapper));

                jdbcCall.compile();

                storedProcedureContainer.put(queryAnnotation.name(), jdbcCall);
            }
        }
    }

    private Set<SqlParameter> getDeclaredParameters(CustomStoredProcedureParameter[] procedureParameters) {
        Set<SqlParameter> parameters = new HashSet<>();
        for (CustomStoredProcedureParameter procedureParameter : procedureParameters) {
            if (procedureParameter.mode().equals(ParameterMode.IN)) {
                parameters.add(new SqlParameter(procedureParameter.name(), procedureParameter.type()));
            }
            if (procedureParameter.mode().equals(ParameterMode.OUT)) {
                parameters.add(new SqlOutParameter(procedureParameter.name(), procedureParameter.type()));
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }

    private Map<String, RowMapper<?>> getDeclaredRowMappers(ProcedureRowMapper[] resultSetMappers, ProcedureResultClass[] simpleResultSetMappers) {
        Map<String, RowMapper<?>> mappers = new HashMap<>();
        if (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(simpleResultSetMappers)) {
            for (ProcedureResultClass procedureResultClass : simpleResultSetMappers) {
                mappers.put(procedureResultClass.name(), BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(procedureResultClass.resultClass()));
            }
            return mappers;
        }
        try {
            for (ProcedureRowMapper resultSetMapper : resultSetMappers) {
                mappers.put(resultSetMapper.name(), resultSetMapper.mapper().newInstance());
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mappers;
    }

    public SimpleJdbcCall getProcedure(String name) {
        return storedProcedureContainer.get(name);
    }
}
```

- Supposed to that *@CustomNamedStoredProcedureQueries* must be declared, even when stored Procedure only one, you can change this yourself if want.
- You can use either *ProcedureResultClass* or *ProcedureRowMapper*, not both, it can changed to.

**Examples** (I use oracledb, but with minor change it can be used for another db)

```
@CustomNamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @CustomNamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "getFoo",
                schemeName = "FooScheme",
                packageName = "FooPackage",
                procedureName = "get_Foo",
                resultSetMappers = @ProcedureResultClass(name = "foo_cursor", resultClass = Foo.class),
                parameters = {
                        @CustomStoredProcedureParameter(name = "foo_id", type = OracleTypes.NUMBER, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @CustomStoredProcedureParameter(name = "error_code", type = OracleTypes.NUMBER, mode = ParameterMode.OUT),
                        @CustomStoredProcedureParameter(name = "foo_cursor", type = OracleTypes.CURSOR, mode = ParameterMode.OUT),
                }
        ),
        @CustomNamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "deleteFoo",
                schemeName = "FooScheme",
                packageName = "FooPackage",
                procedureName = "delete_Foo",
                parameters = {
                        @CustomStoredProcedureParameter(name = "foo_id", type = OracleTypes.NUMBER, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @CustomStoredProcedureParameter(name = "error_code", type = OracleTypes.NUMBER, mode = ParameterMode.OUT),
                }
        )
})
public class Foo {
     long id;
     String name;
     int age;

     public void setId(long id) { 
       this.id= id;
     }
     public long getId() { 
       return this.id;
     }

     public void setName(String name) { 
       this.name = name;
     }
     public String getName() { 
       return this.name;
     }

     public void setAge(int age) { 
       this.age = age;
     }
     public int getAge() { 
       return this.age;
     }
}
```

**Call it:**

```
public Foo getFoo(Long fooId) {
        SqlParameterSource sqlParams = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("foo_id", fooId);
        SimpleJdbcCall procedure = projectUtils.getProcedure("getFoo");
        Map<String, Object> result = procedure.execute(sqlParams);
        return ((List<Foo>) result.get("foo_cursor")).get(0);
    }
```

**Tip** - It can be used with custom type(types that stored in bd), like *Array*, for that you need create custom type extended of *AbstractSqlTypeValue* and override **createTypeValue()**, then pass it like others parameters (***carefully tested only on oracle***).

CustomType must be declared on scheme level and higher, on package level it not working, scheme and type must be call in upper case.

```
    @Override
    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection connection, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        if (connection.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)) {
            OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
            return oracleConnection.createARRAY("FOOSCHEME.NUMBERARRAY", this.array); // array pass when customType class init
        }
        return connection.createArrayOf("FOOSCHEME.NUMBERARRAY", this.array);
    }
```