# Call stored procedure in repository without entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a service with spring data jpa which uses multiple datasource. One of the datasource is used as the main storage and Entity is used there and repositories are described. Other datasources are used simply to call stored procedures and functions.
Can you please tell me if I can somehow create a spring data jpa repository for datasource without an entity and use the `@Procedure` annotations to force the function to call the stored procedure I need?
I read about https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations and just wrote my repository implementation. Looking for alternative, more convenient use cases for the spring data jpa api.

Comment: Why don't you simply use JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some entity as JPA is domain driven, refer [Any way to use the `@Procedure` annotation without an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357157/any-way-to-use-the-procedure-annotation-without-an-entity)
and
[Using Spring @Procedure to call StoredProcedure without binding to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524189/using-spring-procedure-to-call-storedprocedure-without-binding-to-a-table)

In my opinion, you should use Just use JDBC template.

Answer (score 1):

CrudRepository or JpaRepository were not designed to work without an <Entity,ID> pair.

You are better off creating a custom repo, inject EntityManager and query from there:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomeQuery(){
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT foo FROM bar");
        query.getResultsList()
        ...
    }

}
```